# Synonyms [bencoding] and [bencode]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

The tags [bencoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bencoding) and [bencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bencode) should be synonyms, with `bencoding` as the main tag (it has the tag wiki) and `bencode` as the synonym that points to it.  The tags mean exactly the same thing and there's no need for two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [bencode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bencode) and [bencoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bencoding) were created 3.5 hours before your meta-request by their one-and-only question [How to bencode non-ascii strings and non-integer numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243023/how-to-bencode-non-ascii-strings-and-non-integer-numbers)

The tag-wiki was added 1.5 hours later, and while it's not anything to write home about, I guess it's good enough as a start.

There's no need to make a synonym for that similar single-use tags, simply burning one of them with a single edit is sufficient. (*done*)
Whether the tag is good enough to keep I'm not convinced about, but I don't see any justification to kill it (yet).